# SendGrid query string from custom fields

Tags: query-string, sendgrid

I'm new to SendGrid and I was wondering if it was possible to create a URL query string with parameters values retrieved from the custom fields.

I want to create a campaign on which the customer will receive an email and when he/she clicks an image within the content it will redirect to another page and fill partially a survey with the values retrieved from the query.

Example
...

Thanks!

Comment: the example was : <a href="mySite/survey?name=[customer_name]&id=[id_customer]

Comment: Resolved, the example given is how example:  mySite/survey?name=[customer_name]&id=[id_customerto get the content fields